# search box empty checking, when the same html for the search box is called on the same page two time with the same id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

The below html for the Search box is in a partial view.And this partial view is called twice in the same page as per the requirements. And the problem is that the below jquery works only for the above search box not for the below one.
Test Case: When i keep above search box empty and enter in below search box, it throws label showing empty string in search box.

Any suggestion would be appreciated....

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("CustomProductSearch", FormMethod.Get, new {        onsubmit = "return check_small_search_form()" }))
 {
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" style="height:33px;" class="form-control" id="small-searchterms" @(Model.AutoCompleteEnabled ? Html.Raw(" autocomplete=\"off\"") : null)
           value="@T("Search.SearchBox.Tooltip")" name="q" onfocus="if(this.value=='@T("Search.SearchBox.Tooltip")')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = '@T("Search.SearchBox.Tooltip")';}" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" id="Search" class="btn btn-default"> @T("Search") </button>
    </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
<label id="SearchEmptyMessage">Please enter some search keyword</label>
}
```

This is my JQuery for the empty checking of the search box

```
function check_small_search_form() 
{  
      if( $(this).$("#small-searchterms").val() == "" || $(this).$("#small-searchterms").val()  == "@searchTooltip") {

            $("#SearchEmptyMessage").show();
            $("#small-searchterms").focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html and `$("#small-searchterms").val()` will only ever get the value of the first one. Use class names instead.

Comment: @Stephen I checked it by applying class instead of id, but again the same problem exist

Comment: You would then need to loop each item in the collection. And why in the world are you not using a model with validation attributes so all this is handled out of the box by MVC (both client and server side)?

Comment: What is the context for `$(this)`? I also don't beleive `$(this).$("#small-searchterms")` is valid chaining.

Comment: @brut, i also tried by removing $(this) from the line, still no changes

Comment: @Stephen, i need to do it from the client side, i cant access models

Comment: What do you mean you cannot access models? You already are by using `Model.AutoCompleteEnabled`!

Comment: @Stephen, Oh sorry for wrong writing, but as per the case, i need to change from the client , i can not write change in model, but i know, u suggested one is better approach